# Error updating RStudio .99

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

Running Rstudio-server and a recent version of R. With the recent upgrade possibilities of RStudio, I wanted to upgrade.

From what I've read, I should be able to do it by simply running the

```
sudo gdebi [package name]
```

However, this gives me a string of errors.

It gets down to 'Setting up studio-server (0.99.441) ...

```
useradd: user 'studio-server' already exists
groupadd: group 'rstudio-server' already exists
rstudio-server stop/waiting
rstudio-server start/running, process 9823
#
```

I have tried started or stopping the server to get it to install, performing an install without these options and can't get it to upgrade. Google and RSeek turned up nothing, so maybe there is something I'm supposed to know but don't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I did: 
- extract what is in the tar or in the .deb
- rename the folder usr/lib/rstudio (just in case)
- make a new directory /rstudio
- copy all the content of the tar in the new folder

You will need sudo permissions to rename and copy. 
What I use is >sudo nautilus
and as allways. Be carefull with what you change with sudo.